# Show that the dual norm of the spectral norm is the nuclear norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-norms, nuclear-norm, spectral-norm

Could someone help me understand why the dual norm of the spectral norm is the nuclear norm?

We can focus on the real field. Given a matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n},$  then the **spectral** norm is defined by

$$\left \| X\right\| = \max\limits_{i \in \{1, \dots, \min\{m,n\}\} }\sigma_i (X)$$

whereas the **nuclear** norm is defined by

$$\left \| X \right \|_* = \sum\limits_{i=1}^ {\min\{m,n\}} \sigma_i (X)$$

Can someone show me the reasoning process? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1142540/proof-that-nuclear-norm-is-convex/1145246#1145246 . The nuclear norm is proved to be convex my proving that it is the dual of the spectral norm.

Comment: @MichaelGrant so does this also implies that the dual norm of nuclear norm is spectral norm?

Comment: That is correct. Norms always come in dual pairs.

Answer (score 18):

I proved it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1142540/proof-that-nuclear-norm-is-convex/1145246#1145246) in a question about whether or not the nuclear norm is convex. I will reproduce the result here. If the mods see fit to close the question as a duplicate that's fine, but they may not since the question itself is different.

Recall that for any norm, the definition of the dual norm
$\|\cdot\|_*$ is
$$\|A\|_* = \sup_{\|Q\|\leq 1} \langle Q, A \rangle.$$
For the nuclear norm, 
$$\|Q\| \triangleq \sigma_1(Q), \quad \|A\|_* \triangleq \sum_i \sigma_i(A).$$
Therefore we seek to prove that
$$\sup_{\sigma_1(Q)\leq 1} \langle Q, A \rangle = 
\sup_{\sigma_1(Q)\leq 1} \mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(Q^HA) = \sum_i \sigma_i(A).$$

We will first prove that $\sup_{\sigma_1(Q)\leq 1} \langle Q, A \rangle \geq \sum_i\sigma_i(A).$ Let $A=U\Sigma V^H=\sum_i \sigma_i u_i v_i^H$ be the singular value decomposition of $A$, and define $\bar{Q}=UV^H=UIV^H$. $\bar{Q}$ is unitary, so all of its singular values are 1, hence $\sigma_1(\bar{Q})=1$. And
$$\langle \bar{Q}, A \rangle = \langle UV^H, U\Sigma V^H \rangle = \mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(VU^HU\Sigma V^H)
= \mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(V^HVU^HU\Sigma) = \mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(\Sigma) = \sum_i \sigma_i.$$
(Note our use of the identity $\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(ABC)=\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(CAB)$; this is always true when both multiplications are well-posed.) Since the supremum cannot be smaller than this single instance, we have
$$\sup_{\sigma_1(Q)\leq 1} \langle Q, A \rangle \geq \langle\bar{Q}, A \rangle = \sum_i \sigma_i(A).$$
Now let's prove the other direction:
$$\sup_{\sigma_1(Q)\leq 1} \langle Q, A \rangle =
\sup_{\sigma_1(Q)\leq 1} \mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(Q^HU\Sigma V^H) =
\sup_{\sigma_1(Q)\leq 1} \mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(V^HQ^HU\Sigma) =
\sup_{\sigma_1(Q)\leq 1} \langle UQV^H, \Sigma \rangle =
\sup_{\sigma_1(Q)\leq 1} \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i (UQV^H)_{ii} =
\sup_{\sigma_1(Q)\leq 1} \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i u_i Q v_i^H \leq
\sup_{\sigma_1(Q)\leq 1} \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i \sigma_1(Q) =
\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i.
$$
The inequality comes from the fact that $\|u_i\|=\|v_i\|=1$, and
$$u_i^H Q v_i \leq \sup_{\|u\|_2=\|v\|_2=1} u^HQv = \sigma_1(Q).$$
Therefore,
$$\sup_{\sigma_1{Q}\leq 1} \langle Q, A \rangle \leq \sum_i \sigma_i(A).$$
We have proven both the $\leq$ and $\geq$ cases, so equality is confirmed.

Comment: Very insightful! Is it also true that $\sup_{\sigma_1{Q}\leq 1} \langle Q, A \rangle = \sup \left\{ Tr(Q^TA) \, | \,  \|Q\|_2 \leq 1 \right\}$?

Comment: Yes the equality holds. They are one an the same object, written in different notations.

Comment: Why is $\sup \langle UQV^H, \Sigma \rangle = \sup \sum \sigma_i(UQV^H)_{ii}$?

Comment: @EvanMata This is by the definition of matrix inner product and that $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix with entries $\{\sigma_i\}_{i=1}^n$