# Equivalence of computing trace norm of matrix

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces, trace, matrix-norms, nuclear-norm

Let $X\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. How to show that the trace norm $\|X\|_\text{tr}$, which is defined as the sum of the singular values of $X$, is equivalent to the following optimization problem?

\begin{array}{ll} \mathop{\text{maximize}}\limits_{Y\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}} & \text{tr}(X^TY)\\ \text{subject to} & Y^TY \preceq I_n\end{array}

Comment: See section 4.2.3.2 of MOSEK Modeling Cookbook https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/sdo.html .

Comment: Thanks! This is what I want. But under equation (19), Is $\sup_{\|Z\|_2\leq 1} \mathrm{tr}(X^T Z)  =
\sup_{\|X\|_2\leq 1} \mathrm{tr}(\Sigma^T U^T ZV)$ a typo? I think it should be $\sup_{\|Z\|_2\leq 1} \mathrm{tr}(\Sigma^T U^T ZV)$.

Comment: I believe you are correct. The next line then follows because $U^T$ and $V$ both have 2-norm = 1, so "unitary invariance" applies.

Comment: Michael Grant wrote about it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1158829/339790). Note that $\|Q\|_2 \leq 1$ is equivalent to $Q^\top Q \preceq I$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is OK in stackexchange but I am trying to answer my own question to explain more about the derivation of the equivalence of trace norm. The reference is mostly from [section 4.2.3.2 of MOSEK Modeling Cookbook](https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/sdo.html).

We first prove that $||A||_{2} \le 1$ is equivalent to $A^{T} A\preceq I$.
\begin{align*}
 & ||A||_{2} \le 1\\
\Leftrightarrow \quad  & \max_{||x||_{2} =1} ||Ax||_{2} \le 1\\
\Leftrightarrow \quad  & \max_{||x||_{2} =1} x^{T} A^{T} Ax\le 1\\
\Leftrightarrow \quad  & \max_{||x||_{2} =1} x^{T}\left( A^{T} A-I\right) x\le 0\\
\Leftrightarrow \quad  & A^{T} A\preceq I
\end{align*}
Then our problem 
\begin{array}{ll} \mathop{\text{maximize}}\limits_{Y\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}} & \text{tr}(X^TY)\\ \text{subject to} & Y^TY \preceq I_n\end{array}
becomes $$\sup _{||Y||_{2} \leq 1}\mathrm{tr} (X^{T} Y)$$
Then we do SVD decomposition to $X$, $X=U\Sigma V^T$,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\sup _{||Z||_{2} \leq 1}\mathrm{tr} (X^{T} Z) & =\sup _{||Z\| _{2} \leq 1}\mathrm{tr} (V\Sigma ^{T} U^{T} Z)\\
 & =\sup _{||Z\| _{2} \leq 1}\mathrm{tr} (\Sigma ^{T} U^{T} ZV)\\
 & =\sup _{\| U^{T} ZV\| _{2} \leq 1}\mathrm{tr} (\Sigma ^{T} U^{T} ZV)\\
 & =\sup _{\| Y\| _{2} \leq 1}\mathrm{tr} (\Sigma ^{T} Y)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
$\mathrm{tr} (V\Sigma ^{T} U^{T} Z) = \mathrm{tr} (\Sigma ^{T} U^{T} ZV)$ follows from the [invariant under cyclic permutations property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)) of trace. And the equivalence of constraint $||Z||_2 \le 1 \Leftrightarrow ||U^T Z V ||_2 \le 1$ follows from the definition of $\ell_2$ norm of matrix.
And using the unitary invariance of the norm $||\cdot||_2$ again. We can consider $Y=\mathbf{diag}(y_1, \dots, y_p)$.
$$\sup_{\|Z\|_2\leq 1} \mathrm{tr}(X^T Z) = \sup_{|y_i| \leq 1} \sum_{i=1}^p \sigma_i y_i = \sum_{i=1}^p \sigma_i$$