# How calculate the trace norm via convex optimization?

Tags: matrices, convex-optimization, normed-spaces, matrix-norms, nuclear-norm

<sub>I am taking the convex optimization course by CMU (though I am not a CMU student), and got stuck on this problem.</sub>

---

> Formally, show that computing $\left \| X \right \|_{tr}$ can be expressed as the following convex optimization problem:
> $$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{{Y \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}}}{\text{maximize}} & \mbox{tr} \left( X^T Y \right)\\ \text{subject to} & \begin{pmatrix}  I_{m} & Y \\ Y^{T} & I_{n} \end{pmatrix} \succeq 0\end{array}$$
> where $I_{p}$ is the $p \times p$ identity matrix.

Any help would be appropriated.

Comment: Did you mean appreciated?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2717312/339790).

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1963711/339790).

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1158798/339790)

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thank you so much for your editing and the related questions! They are very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

What are the eigenvalues of $$\begin{pmatrix}  I_{m} & Y \\ Y^{T} & I_{n} \end{pmatrix}?$$ Well, consider an eigenvector $[p, q].$ Then:

$$ p + Y q = \lambda p,$$
and

$$Y^{T}p + q = \lambda q.$$

We see that $$Y q = (\lambda - 1) p,$$ while $$Y^{T} p = (\lambda - 1) q.$$ Applying $Y$ to the second equation we see that $$YY^{T} p = (\lambda -1)^2.$$

So the block matrix is positive semidefinite if and only if $I\succeq YY^{T},$ which is exactly the condition in [the question pointed out by Rodrigo.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2717312/equivalence-of-computing-trace-norm-of-matrix)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I believe my block matrix is the same as that of the pointed question. However, I am a bit confused about your last equation. Did you mean $YY^{T}=(\lambda-1)^{2}\times I_{m}$? If that is the case, then $YY^{T}\preceq I_{m}$ implies $0\leqslant \lambda\leqslant 2$, which is not required by the problem description, am I wrong?