# Maximize $\langle {\bf A} , {\bf X} \rangle$ subject to $\| {\bf X} \|_* \leq 1$

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-optimization, matrix-norms, nuclear-norm

> Given ${\bf A} \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$, $$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & \langle {\bf A} , {\bf X} \rangle\\ \text{subject to} & \| {\bf X} \|_* \leq 1\end{array}$$ where $\| \cdot \|_*$ denotes the nuclear norm.

---

Though I know something about the spectral norm, I know almost nothing about the nuclear norm,  dual norms, convex analysis, etc.  Since I am utterly unqualified to answer this on my own, I post this question.

---

Related:

- [Show that the dual norm of the spectral norm is the nuclear norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1158798/339790)
- [Maximize $\langle \mathrm A , \mathrm X \rangle$ subject to $\| \mathrm X \|_2 \leq 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1963711/339790)

Comment: A direct proof of the duality between the nuclear norm and the spectral norm can be found in the second part of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1158829) by Michael Grant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that $\| X \|_*$ is the nuclear norm of $X$. Then the function $f$ defined by
$$
f(A) = \sup_{\| X \|_* \leq 1} \langle A, X \rangle
$$
is by definition the dual of the nuclear norm. But a standard result is that the dual of the nuclear norm is the spectral norm. Thus
$$
f(A) = \sigma_\max(A),
$$ the largest singular value of .

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to formulate using CVX, wbich will convert it to an SDP. How reliably and quickly it solves depends on the size and numerics of the problem.

```
cvx_begin
variable X(m,n)
minimize(trace(A'*X))
norm_nuc(A) <= 1
cvx_end
```

Comment: But, there's an analytical solution because the dual of the nuclear norm is the spectral norm. No need to solve an SDP.