# Is the dual norm of an induced norm an induced norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

I think [this Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1112355/dual-norm-of-induced-norm-on-matrices) gets close to answering this, but does not provide a full response.
 If you have some induced matrix norm $\|\cdot\|_{\|\cdot\|', \|\cdot\|'}$ induced by the vector norm $\|\cdot\|'$, I'm wondering if is it the dual of this norm (i.e. $\|\cdot\|_{\|\cdot\|', \|\cdot\|'}^D$) also an induced norm?
 Furthermore, if $\|\cdot\|_{\|\cdot\|', \|\cdot\|'}^D$ is an induced norm, is there a relationship between the vector norm $\|\cdot\|'$ and the vector norm which would induce $\|\cdot\|_{\|\cdot\|', \|\cdot\|'}^D$?

I was considering trying to work with what I think is just an unnamed Theorem,
$$
\|A\|_{\|\cdot\|, \|\cdot\|} = \|A^*\|_{\|\cdot\|^D, \|\cdot\|^D},
$$ but that doesn't seem to be getting me anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. E.g. the dual norm of the induced $2$-norm is the trace norm (a.k.a. nuclear norm or Schatten $1$-norm), but for $2\times2$ or larger matrices, the trace norm is not an induced norm because $\|I_n\|_{\operatorname{tr}}=n\ne1$.